# Stripe but won´t charge using Ajax to post token

Tags: php, ajax

I have the following fairly basic implementation of Stripe. It successfully creates a new customer but it won´t charge and return the "SUCCESS ERROR" message in the console. The token seems to be created correctly so my guess is i am missing something in the charge.php.

NOTE: I have not used composer to install stripe but load the init.php in config.php (could that be the problem?). Also is the  neccessary even though i use ajax?(removing it won´t solve the problem though)

Index.php

```
<?php require_once('stripe/config.php'); ?>
<form action="charge.php" method="post">
<script src="https://checkout.stripe.com/checkout.js"></script>
<button id="customButton">Purchase</button>
<script>
var handler = StripeCheckout.configure({
key: 'pk_test_*******************',
token: function(token) {
  // Use the token to create the charge with a server-side script.
  // You can access the token ID with `token.id`
  console.log(token)
  $.ajax({
      url: 'stripe/charge.php',
      type: 'post',
      data: {tokenid: token.id, email: token.email},
      success: function(data) {
        if (data == 'success') {
            console.log("Card successfully charged!");
        }
        else {
            console.log("Success Error!");
        }

      },
      error: function(data) {
        console.log("Ajax Error!");
        console.log(data);
      }
    }); // end ajax call
    }
  });

  $('#customButton').on('click', function(e) {
    // Open Checkout with further options
    handler.open({
      name: 'shipping free',
      description: '2 widgets',
      amount: 2000
    });
e.preventDefault();
  });

  // Close Checkout on page navigation
  $(window).on('popstate', function() {
    handler.close();
  });
</script>
</form>
```

CONFIG.PHP

```
<?php require_once('init.php');

$stripe = array(
secret_key      => 'sk_test_************************',
publishable_key => 'pk_test_************************'
);

Stripe::setApiKey($stripe['secret_key']);
?>
```

CHARGE.PHP

```
<?php require_once('/config.php');

  $tokenid = $_POST['tokenid'];
  $email = $_POST['email'];

  $customer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
      'email' => $email,
      'card'  => $tokenid
  ));

  $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
      'email' => $email,
      'card'  => $tokenid
      'amount'   => 5000,
      'currency' => 'usd',

  ));

  echo '<h1>Successfully charged $50.00!</h1>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line, 'card'  => $tokenid. you are missing comma(,).

Add comma in that line.

```
$charge = \Stripe\Charge::create(array(
      'email' => $email,
      'card'  => $tokenid,
      'amount'   => 5000,
      'currency' => 'usd',

  ));
```